# NightmareJS screenshot callback

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, nightmare

I'm using this framework to make screenshots of several urls. The process of taking the screenshot is async, and the method does not provide a way to execute a callback, and I want to execute a callback when each screenshot is made on this script:

```
nightmare = new Nightmare();
urls.forEach(function (url) {
    nightmare.goto(url).screenshot(path);
});

nightmare.run(function () {
  console.log('finished all');
});
```

Any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to do this, with the "use" method for executing plugins.

```
nightmare = new Nightmare();
urls.forEach(function (url) {
    nightmare.goto(url).screenshot(path).use(function () {
        console.log('finished one');
    });
});

nightmare.run(function () {
    console.log('finished all');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be the purpose of the `run()` method.  You probably want to set up and run each screenshot within the loop, since the `screenshot()` method relies on the phandomjs method `render()`, and [`render()` is strictly synchronous](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11084) (at least as of a year ago):

```
urls.forEach(function (url) {
    nightmare = new Nightmare();
    nightmare.goto(url).screenshot(path).run(function(err, nightmare) {
        console.log('this executes when your screenshot completes');
        // run() appropriately tears down the nightmare instance
    });
});

console.log('finished all');
```

You don't gain any asynchronous benefits from setting up all the screenshots at once, and "finished all" is guaranteed to only run once all screenshots have been rendered.

Alternatively, in the nightmarejs source, it looks like `screenshot()` *does* take a second `done` parameter that appears to be a callback, but it passes it directly into the phantomjs `render()` method, and as seen in the above link there was some resistance to allowing that method to take a callback.

Comment: Now that I've looked into the source rather than rely on examples, it appears that calling run in a loop will likely present issues.  You can solve this by setting up a new Nightmare instance for each screenshot.  Also, the `screenshot()` method *does* take a 2nd `done` parameter, that looks like a callback though it passes it in directly to phantomjs and I don't know what it does with it.  The `render()` method that it's calling is synchronous, so you will have a big synchronous action in the middle of each iteration regardless.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the stuff that I've seen in the source.

Comment: PhantomJS' render doesn't take a callback but the `phantom` bridge's render does and this is what is used by Nightmare. This should solve the mystery.

Comment: It does, indeed, @ArtjomB., thank you.  And so there you go, you can use a callback directly.

Comment: @ArtjomB. what you said it's the answer, do you want to add it as answer?

Comment: @fernandopasik Yes, I want to, but I can't right now. Re-installed node and now nothing works. :(

Comment: @ArtjomB. just copy my code and add the callback to the screenshot function

Comment: There's a problem, the done callback can not be overwritten as it blocks the queue of nightmarejs