# Nightmare type result of function which is using taken screenshot

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

Hey I am trying to take a screenshot of an element with nightmare and than I want to extract text from this screenshot with a function and use the result of this in `nightmare.type()`. The Problem is when I use `nightmare.run()` I get an error that the screenshot does not exist. How can I fix this? This is my code:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var Screenshot = require('nightmare-screenshot');

var nightmare = new Nightmare();
nightmare.goto('website');
//Takes screenshot of element
nightmare.use(Screenshot.screenshotSelector('screenshot' + i + '.png', 'img[id="yw0"]'));
nightmare.type('input[id=AuthForm_login]', username);
nightmare.type('input[id=AuthForm_password]', password);

nightmare.type('input[id=upload]', image.decodeFile('screenshot' + i + '.png', function(err, result){
    //Returns Text from the Screenshot taken above!
    return result.text;
}));
nightmare.run();
```

When I remove the line:

```
nightmare.type('input[id=upload]', image.decodeFile('screenshot' + i + '.png', function(err, result){
        //Returns Text from the Screenshot taken above!
        return result.text;
    }));
```

Everything works fine and I get a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

As nightmare uses Phantomjs you can do it that way, although I found this below that should help.

Credit to @fernandopasik who said:

> I found a way to do this, with the "use" method for executing plugins.
>
> ```
> nightmare = new Nightmare(); urls.forEach(function (url) {
>     nightmare.goto(url).screenshot(path).use(function () {
>         console.log('finished one');
>     }); });
>
> nightmare.run(function () {
>     console.log('finished all'); });
> ```

[NightmareJS screenshot callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410157/nightmarejs-screenshot-callback)

Comment: I can't use this because when `nightmare.run()` it imediatly throws out the error and i need to process the image first and reuse it later in the same nightmare que